# Erro com Django e Cloudinary - can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, cloud

Estou tentando fazer uma app simples:
Fiz o tutorial do [Django Girls](https://www.gitbook.com/book/djangogirls/djangogirls-tutorial/details) e agora estou tentando usar o mesmo incluindo também uma imagem usando o [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/)

Porem estou tendo o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O erro acontece na linha `upload_result = cloudinary.uploader.upload(file)` do arquivo `views.py`

Segue codigo

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from cloudinary.models import CloudinaryField

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    image_url = CloudinaryField('imagem', blank=True, null=True)

def publish(sefl):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

`views.py`

```
def post_new(request):
    upload_result = None
    thumbnail = None

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            file = request.FILES['image_url']
            if file:
                upload_result = cloudinary.uploader.upload(file)
                thumbnail, option = cloudinary_url(upload_result['public_id'], format="jpg", crop="fill", width=100, height=100)

            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

`post_edit.html`

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% load cloudinary %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Nova postagem</h1>

    <form action="" method="post" class="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form.as_table }}

        <br />
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-success">
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Se alguem puder, incluir a tag **cloudinary**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estava com este mesmo problema, acontece que a biblioteca ficou incompatível com algumas novas funções do Python 3.x e corrigiram os mesmos na versão 1.3.1

**Atualiza a versão do pacote do Cloudinary para 1.3.1**

Comment: Muito obrigado! Deu certo!